# Kanban javascript html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn javascript with an exercise where I try to create a kanban but I'm stuck. I can't implement drag and drop. Anyone to help me? (ps I welcome any criticism regarding the code, I'm also here to learn)

I leave you the code below

```js
const button = document.getElementById("dataEntryButton");
const boxDataContainer = document.getElementById("boxDataContainer");
const boxDataContainer1 = document.getElementById("boxDataContainer1");
const containerDataEntry = document.getElementById("containerDataEntry");

const createTable = (data) => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const text = document.createElement("h1");
  const deleteTable = document.createElement("button");
  const makeDraggable = document.createAttribute("#")

  text.innerText = data;
  deleteTable.innerText = "Delete Table";

  deleteTable.addEventListener("click", () => {
    boxDataContainer.removeChild(div)
  });

  div.appendChild(text);
  div.appendChild(deleteTable)

  return (div);
}

dataEntryButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const data = containerDataEntry.value;

  const table = createTable(data);

  boxDataContainer.appendChild(table);
});
```

```css
#boxDataEntry {
  margin: 10px;
}

.dropArea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxDataEntry">
  <textarea id="containerDataEntry" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <button id="dataEntryButton">Enter</button>
</div>

<div id="boxDataContainer" class="dropArea"></div>
<div id="boxDataContainer1" class="dropArea"></div>
```

idk what to do, the point where I stopped is the one where I have to implement the drag and drop of the elements from one box to another and vice versa

Comment: I hope I didn't make a mistake translating the text of the code into English, I'm not very good at this language yet hehe

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. I left the errors in there that I saw, so you may need to fix them.  The one I noticed was `id="boxDataContainer dropArea"` in your HTML.  An element ID needs to be a single string with no spaces. Perhaps you meant to use a `class` instead?

Comment: Yeah, he meant class... However there are more issues. [createAttribute(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createAttribute) does not work that way and NEVER create an event listener inside another eventListener. You want to [delegate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) and you need to implement the [drag and drop api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) - for now it looks like you code by wishful thinking